# Rotate and Save captured image without using bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, android-canvas

I want to **rotate** and **save** my Captured Image using Android **Native Camera** to sdcard. As native cameras is in **landscape** by default. But the I don't want to use bitmap. Is it possible to do so ? please help. I am new to android development.

As my image is rotated by 90 degrees I need to rotate it using **Bitmap** before saving.
But on some devices **bmp** is coming **null**.

**Camera Activity** Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**ManifestFile**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.androiddms.CameraActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_camera"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
</activity>
```

**Camera Activity.java**

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);

bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,fos);
```

Comment: What problem you are facing with bitmap ?

Comment: Bitmap is using a lot of memory . Although some techniques exist to handle them. But I just wanted to try if I could save **Captured Image** without using **Bitmaps** at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `onActivityResult` after taking picture from camera and show your captured picture on `ImageView`. `Bitmap` takes memory but you should handle it. Follow the following steps below hopefully solve your Problem

**STEP 1:** open `camera Intent` and capture image from it:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;

Bitmap bmp;

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

**STEP 2:** `override onActivityResult` Method

```
@Override   
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            {               
                Uri uri = (Uri) data.getData();

                try 
                {
                    bmp = decodeUri(uri);

                    your_image_view.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                } 
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**STEP 3:** copy below method and paste it in your `Activity`

```
private Bitmap decodeUri(Uri selectedImage) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;

        int scale = 1;

        while (true) 
        {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) 
            {
                break;
            }
            width_tmp /= 2;

            height_tmp /= 2;

            scale *= 2;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        o2.inSampleSize = scale;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);
    }
```

and you are done after following these steps you will be able to capture image from camera and set it to your imageview without having memory error. Hope this will help you.